# No columns in datasheet view

Tags: 2010, datasheet

I am unable to see any columns in the datasheet view of any list. Here's what I see:
[image: no columns in datasheet view]

My coworker is able to see all columns as expected.

Any ideas why this may be the case?

Comment: did you try with different browser?

Comment: It's an ActiveX control, and requires IE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away after a repair of my MS Office installation.